# Instancing in Three.JS

Tags: three.js, geometry-instancing

It might be me, as I'm not very experienced with Three.js, but the Three.js instancing example seems very vague.

I thought BufferGeometries were automatically created from Geometries in the new Three.js, and I don't understand why a shader is being added to the example.

The documentation says nothing about instancing. Searching up 'inst' in the Three.js docs already gives 0 results.

Is there someone who would give me a simple example?

Comment: Just a thought, do you need instancing? If you're new to computer graphics it's probably throwing yourself in the deep end pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I do. I basically have meshes where both the geometry and material are the same to each other and are moving independent from each other. By the way, I do question how I would acquire less draw calls on those meshes where the geometry is the same but the material isn't.

Comment: try the code at http://jsdo.it/cx20/i0jN comments are in moonspeak, but it is short enough to be readable without them